# Trying to upgrade headers when my version is already ahead

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel

So I am now stuck and unable. I have Kernel `4.10.0` but the upgrader is trying to install `4.4.0`

**dpkg -s linux-headers-$(uname -r)**

```
Package: linux-headers-4.10.0-24-generic
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: devel
Installed-Size: 7361
Maintainer: Ubuntu Kernel Team <kernel-team@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: linux-hwe-edge
Version: 4.10.0-24.28~16.04.1
Provides: linux-headers, linux-headers-3.0
Depends: linux-headers-4.10.0-24, libc6 (>= 2.14), libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0)
Description: Linux kernel headers for version 4.10.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
 This package provides kernel header files for version 4.10.0 on
 64 bit x86 SMP.
 .
 This is for sites that want the latest kernel headers.  Please read
 /usr/share/doc/linux-headers-4.10.0-24/debian.README.gz for details.
```

**sudo apt-get upgrade**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libssl1.0.2 linux-headers-4.4.0-81 linux-headers-4.4.0-81-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-good libjasper1 liblcms2-utils libnet-dns-perl
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 4 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up shim-signed (1.32~16.04.1+0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install.real: error: cannot find EFI directory.
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 shim-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So simply, would I be able to upgrade again? I don't believe this is an issue with grub as its suggestion.

**My installation types**

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL                     UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sdf                                                                          
├─sdf7 ext4                             63c4634f-eed3-4c94-b749-8fb82b65302c /media/hutber/63c4634f-eed3-4c94-b749-8fb82b65302c
├─sdf5 swap                             af40a27f-eacd-466c-bc84-35a09b8f0019 
├─sdf1 ntfs   Videos                    94887008886FE768                     /media/hutber/Videos
├─sdf6 ext4                             d734c4c0-0274-4c3b-8c58-ec93be3299bf /media/hutber/d734c4c0-0274-4c3b-8c58-ec93be3299bf
└─sdf2                                                                       
sdd                                                                          
├─sdd2 ntfs   Downloads                 2AAA6CBEAA6C87E1                     /mnt/downloads
└─sdd1                                                                       
sdb                                                                          
├─sdb2 ntfs   Seagate Backup Plus Drive FE16E51816E4D327                     /mnt/8tbinternal
└─sdb1                                                                       
sdg                                                                          
└─sdg1 ntfs   Mayfield 1516             D07888C87888AEB2                     /mnt/mayfield
sde                                                                          
└─sde1 ntfs   Users                     D050F8B650F8A47E                     /mnt/users
sdc                                                                          
├─sdc2 swap                             0cd5ddcd-8e71-43e1-b9a9-3f199207decd [SWAP]
└─sdc1 ext4                             486e4e71-6862-45b1-b27f-770efc47adbd /
sda                                                                          
├─sda4 ntfs                             E036A40336A3D934                     /mnt/c
├─sda2 vfat                             7289-D464                            
├─sda5 ntfs                             8A884AE5884ACEFF                     
├─sda3                                                                       
└─sda1 ntfs   Recovery                  8E7683287683105F                     
sdh                                                                          
├─sdh1                                                                       
└─sdh2 ntfs   Seagate Backup Plus Drive E8B01862B0183990                     /mnt/newexternal
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have an EFI installation of Grub? What's the output of `sudo lsblk -f`?

Comment: Updated the questions pal